# Changing Text Color of Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Can you change the text color of `android.R.layout.test_list_item` or it's already fixed?

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner1.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner_items,android.R.layout.test_list_item));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed in as much as the layout is what it is. For info, this is android.R.layout.test_list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="3dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

If you want a different color, just create your own layout, similar to this one with the changes you want such as adding the android:textColor attribute. Then refer to that when creating the adapter. For example:

```
spinner1.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.spinner_items, R.layout.my_test_list_item));
```

Comment: Did you mean I'll create a new android xml layout in res/layout named my_test_list_item with a customized textview?

Comment: Yep, exactly like that.